# Repeat value in new column till change is detected pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe as follows :

```
+-------------------+------------+
|               time|cycle_number|
+-------------------+------------+
|2020-11-01 00:00:01|           1|#1
|2020-11-01 00:00:31|           0|#1
|2020-11-01 00:00:37|           0|#1
|2020-11-01 00:00:40|           0|#1
|2020-11-01 00:00:43|           0|#1
|2020-11-01 00:00:49|           0|#1
|2020-11-01 00:00:58|           2|#2
|2020-11-01 00:01:07|           0|#2
|2020-11-01 00:01:16|           0|#2
|2020-11-01 00:01:19|           0|#2
|2020-11-01 00:01:25|           0|#2
|2020-11-01 00:01:37|           0|#2
|2020-11-01 00:01:52|           3|#3
|2020-11-01 00:02:04|           0|#3
|2020-11-01 00:02:07|           0|#3
|2020-11-01 00:02:23|           0|#3
|2020-11-01 00:02:29|           4|#4
|2020-11-01 00:02:35|           0|#4
|2020-11-01 00:02:50|           5|#5
|2020-11-01 00:03:08|           0|#5
+-------------------+------------+
```

I want to create new column in which `1` repeat till `2` occurs and then `2` and so on.

I have tried to do the following but it is adding `1` to cycle_number and giving as `3` instead of `2` and then `3` repeats :

```
windowSpecCycle = Window.orderBy(df['time'].asc())
df = df.withColumn(
        "cycleChange",
        (f.col("cycle_number") != f.lag("cycle_number").over(windowSpecCycle)).cast("int")
    ).withColumn(
        "indicator",
        (~((f.col("cycleChange") == 0))).cast("int")
    ).withColumn(
        "group",
        f.sum(f.col("indicator")).over(windowSpec.rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
    )
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can easily achieve that with following code:

```
w = Window.orderBy("time").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
df = df.withColumn("result", max("cycle_number").over(w))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following changes are needed to accomplish the same :

```
windowSpecCycle = Window.orderBy(df['time'].asc())
df = df.withColumn('value_1', f.when(f.col('cycle_number') > 0, f.lit(1)).otherwise(f.lit(0)))
df = df.withColumn('cum_sum', 
f.sum('value_1').over(windowSpecCycle).alias('cumsum').cast(StringType()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
colExpr = F.first(F.col("cycle_number")).over(Window.partitionBy(F.sum(F.col("cycle_number")).over(Window.rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow).orderBy(F.col("time")))))

df.withColumn("cycle_number",colExpr).show()
```

**Result**

```
+-------------------+------------+
|time               |cycle_number|
+-------------------+------------+
|2020-11-01 00:00:01|1           |
|2020-11-01 00:00:31|1           |
|2020-11-01 00:00:37|1           |
|2020-11-01 00:00:40|1           |
|2020-11-01 00:00:43|1           |
|2020-11-01 00:00:49|1           |
|2020-11-01 00:00:58|2           |
|2020-11-01 00:01:07|2           |
|2020-11-01 00:01:16|2           |
|2020-11-01 00:01:19|2           |
|2020-11-01 00:01:25|2           |
|2020-11-01 00:01:37|2           |
|2020-11-01 00:01:52|3           |
|2020-11-01 00:02:04|3           |
|2020-11-01 00:02:07|3           |
|2020-11-01 00:02:23|3           |
|2020-11-01 00:02:29|4           |
|2020-11-01 00:02:35|4           |
|2020-11-01 00:02:50|5           |
|2020-11-01 00:03:08|5           |
+-------------------+------------+
```